# How to get the country and state from a paypal transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I would like to know how to obtain the country and state, from the billing address, in a paypal transaction.

So far I can get a transaction object via the code below:

```
  # ...
  def self.paypal_transaction_details(txn_id)
    @api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant.new
    get_transaction_details = @api.build_get_transaction_details({:TransactionID => txn_id })
    response = @api.get_transaction_details(get_transaction_details)
  end
```

Is it possible to get the location info? Or should I use geocoder to get the country and state from the ip address?

Reference: https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-ruby

**Response:**

```
response.PaymentTransactionDetails.PayerInfo.Address
 => #<PayPal::SDK::Merchant::DataTypes::AddressType:0x007fd58f604660 @AddressOwner="PayPal", @AddressStatus="None">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you get transaction details you should be able to get any address used in the payment. However, be aware that PayPal does not always have a "billing address" -- that's a credit card concept. PayPal does not normally send bills, so accounts do not have a billing address by default. If goods are shipped then there is a shipping address, and all accounts do have a country code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using this [gem 'paypal-sdk-rest'](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK)

but if you are, when you  Create Payment 
you can do

```
require 'paypal-sdk-rest'
include PayPal::SDK::REST

PayPal::SDK::REST.set_config(
  :mode => "sandbox", # "sandbox" or "live"
  :client_id => "EBWKjlELKMYqRNQ6sYvFo64FtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM",
  :client_secret => "EO422dn3gQLgDbuwqTjzrFgFtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM")

# Build Payment object
@payment = Payment.new({
  :intent => "sale",
  :payer => {
    :payment_method => "credit_card",
    :funding_instruments => [{
      :credit_card => {
        :type => "visa",
        :number => "4567516310777851",
        :expire_month => "11",
        :expire_year => "2018",
        :cvv2 => "874",
        :first_name => "Joe",
        :last_name => "Shopper",
        :billing_address => {
          :line1 => "52 N Main ST",
          :city => "Johnstown",
          :state => "OH",
          :postal_code => "43210",
          :country_code => "US" }}}]},
  :transactions => [{
    :item_list => {
      :items => [{
        :name => "item",
        :sku => "item",
        :price => "1",
        :currency => "USD",
        :quantity => 1 }]},
    :amount => {
      :total => "1.00",
      :currency => "USD" },
    :description => "This is the payment transaction description." }]})

# Create Payment and return the status(true or false)
if @payment.create
  @payment.id     # Payment Id
else
  @payment.error  # Error Hash
end
```

I hope that this helps. 
ps.
you have to request the info first, if not there would be nil or '' when you want to get them back

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using the merchant-sdk-ruby gem. And the payment is handled directly via paypal. Our system gets a notification via the IPN URL